# What container holds a 26-pound bag of kibble?

Tags: dogs

I would like to transfer the contents of a 26-pound bag of dry dog food from the bag to a more convenient container.

Any suggestions for a container to hold that amount, or a method for finding such a container?

How does one determine if a container is likely to hold an entire bag? Trial and error can be messy.

(This might be useful for other dry pet foods too. Maybe for other dry goods generally)

Comment: Down-Voter: Please leave a criticism along with your vote.

Comment: I imagine that down voters are focusing the fact this is a question about one size of one brand of dog food.  Also the link in the question makes it feel like spam.  Maybe if you edit the question to be about any 25 pound of pet food, remove the spammy link and update your answer to focus on your solution?  Your solution is cool, but the spam feeling of the Q&A just feels wrong.

Comment: Proposed an edit to address the concern voiced....

Comment: @JamesJenkins Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: I grant that this is something of a "shopping question", but because it's being answered with general solutions rather than specific products I think it's defendable.

Comment: Doesn't make it any less opinion based @keshlam

Comment: @JustDoIt: Hm. It's a goid answer, but you may be right that it's a better one for a lifehacks-like discussion than for Pets. I'm inclined to wait snd see what happens, but de gustibus.

Comment: Narrowly focused questions on a very specific issue is exactly [what inspired StackOverflow](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/09/15.html). As for brands, **kibble density varies** and therefore the answer varies. Furthermore on brands, look at the cars Stack Exchange where specific sizes of specific parts on specific models from specific vendors is  common. Nevertheless, I did modify the Question and the Answer to focus on the calculation method by which a person may determine their own fitting solution.

Comment: My concerns are that it sounds like a shopping question (Added in that you're asking for suggestions and not answers). And with your answer it doesn't really seem to solve it for anyone but yourself. Normally I'd propose an edit to make it more of a mathematical question, but it would invalidate your answer. My version of the question would be [something like this](http://pastebin.com/gR8qzKB9)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 7-Gallon Bucket

That 26-pound bag happens to just fit a 7-gallon bucket available from brewers supply companies with just a bit of room to spare.

Add a screw-type lid from a home building supply company and you have a nice complete kibble storage system.

## Calculation

My clever friend determined this would work by weighing a cup of the kibble, and dividing that weight into the 26 pounds to determine how many cups of kibble are in a bag. The she divided the 7 gallon volume to get the number of cups would fit in the bucket. Voilà.

You could apply this strategy to your own kibble and your own container under consideration.

[image]

Comment: Nice solution. For 14-pound bags of catfood, I found that the pet store had large "pourable" containers that were about the right size. Bigger containers are great for bulk goods generally -- cat litter (clean or used), 30-pound bags of rice (much cheaper than typical convenience sizes), etc.

Answer (score 1):

Many products will display the expected mass of food expected to accommodate. I have a 30lb rated product that holds a 26lb bag just fine.

If you'd rather try and calculate - you can estimate that 3.75 lbs of typical dog food will fill roughly the volume of 1 gallon (this calculation is dependent on the specific density of the dog food - but we'll just estimate with known values). With that, we can also estimate the previous answer of a 7 gallon bucket should also work (max mass of about 26.25 lbs).

Answer (score 1):

I used a 17 gallon tub with an attached folding lid, purchased from Home Depot. I did not want to have to deal with the lid while my dog danced around me excited for food, so I chose the folding lid to address that issue. I was able to fit all of a 50 lb bag of kibble into the container.